# .htaccess 301 Redirect for specific IP address only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Please help I've tried hard but it just doesn't work.

What i'm trying to accomplish is simply redirect all users within our company network (all with the same external ip address, let's say 192.168.0.1) to htp://start.example.com/page_2 when they visit htp://start.example.com/page_1. All other ip addresses should be just fine visiting htp://start.example.com/page_1.

Ive tried these 2 rules:

1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.1$
Redirect 301 /page_1  http://start.example.com/page_2
```

*In this case the redirect only works when the ip check is disabled.*

2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page_2$
RewriteRule .* http://start.example.com/page_2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

*In this case the redirect only works when the path check is disabled.*

What is wrong?

**Oké, found the solution,** Somehow the position of the redirect just didn't work, i moved it to the top of the document and now it works with the following syntax. In the example I've added an extra IP check and a User agent "Windows" check.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.0\.1$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows
RewriteRule page_1$ http://start.example.com/page_2 [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: Oh, i know the links in the text are htp instead of http, this was done to post this question, there was a check build in to prevent users using to many links. not really helpful in this case.

Comment: I think you should check out a different stackexchange (https://serverfault.com/) that I believe are more focused on these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a mix of two unrelated directives [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) from [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html).
The `RewriteCond` has no associated `RewriteRule`.

The second one cannot work, because `REQUEST_URI` always contains the leading slash. The proper condition would be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_2$
```

The rule rewrites anything (`.*`) to `page_2`, not just `page_1`. To restrict this properly, this should be

```
RewriteRule ^page_1$ http://start.example.com/page_2 [R,L,NC]
```

In case there are other redirects, e.g. adding a path at the end, the condition should reflect this this too by removing the end of string marker `$`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_2
```

This matches anything starting with `/page_2`.

You may also exclude other paths from redirection, separated with a vertical bar

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page_2|page_3)
```

---

Finally, *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: Ha Olaf, thanks you for your reply, I've tried your solution but now the page_2 is not displayed because of to many redirects…

Comment: @nielsvoo This shouldn't happen, because `page_2` is excluded by this condition. Maybe there are other rules/redirects causing this. Is `page_2` a real static file or maybe anything else, like a directory?

Comment: Hi Olaf, page_2 is a path alias on a Drupal 8 site. There are some redirects in the .htaccess file, all done by Drupal self.

Comment: @nielsvoo Please see updated answer, but maybe this is more than what SO can provide.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for all the help the location was one of the problems, I've moved it to the top and now it works well. See the update above.

Comment: @nielsvoo If I had asked your question and gotten Olaf's help, I would have also given him credit for giving you the preferred answer. Maybe there's a check mark on you screen you can click? (He already has many multiples of my paltry points, but he's done the work for more!) One vote from the cheap seats!